# Cannot understand issue! Input tensor must be at least 2D

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have written this simple program to make a prediction (do not mind that there is no train/test split). `x` is a 2D input array of size 40k, 4.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import load

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

tf.get_logger().setLevel('INFO')
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(1)

x = load('dataset/metadata/x.npy')
y = load('dataset/metadata/y.npy')

meta_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ]
)
meta_model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()]
)
meta_model.fit(x, y, batch_size=25, epochs=10, verbose=2)

for i in range (10):
    print(y[i], " vs ", meta_model(x[i]))
```

In the final few lines I am attempting to make the model output a prediction (also I am aware that the prediction is happening on the same data which it is using to learn, I am simply trying to get the model to work). I cannot understand why I am getting the following error (on the last line):

```
Input tensor must be at least 2D: [3]
```

Can anyone help explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Print the shape of x. Make sure it's at least 2D, as the interpreter is telling you. Get used to printing the shape of things in numpy/pandas/TF, it will save you a lot of time from trying to guess what's going on. So here, look at the shape of `x[i]`.

Comment: `x[i]` is not a 2D array, because it shouldn't be. Is that not enough? I am only expecting to make a single prediction.

Comment: As I type this I realise that the prediction method expects a batch to be called in not a single record... Sorry lol.

Comment: You are feeding x[i] to the first dense layer, created by `layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'),`. That layer has 3 neurons, so you the input needs to be a vector of length 3. That's a 2D input - namely, a vector. `x[i]` should be a vector too.

Comment: Oh, and you've specified a batch, yes..